# Aspect Ratio Fitting for TV Screen

Tags: resolution

I am currently working on a project that requires me to put together an image to be presented on a TV screen.  My assumption is that the TV screen size and resolution shouldn't matter as long as I have my aspect ratio correct and use a high res image.  I have my image set to 9:16 aspect ratio and 2400x2400 resolution, so the image should fit to fill the entire TV screen, correct?  I am under the impression that my image should fit to fill the screen unless the TV itself has some weird aspect ratio settings but would really love to be corrected if I am wrong.

Comment: Eh . . . an image can't be 9:16 if it is 2400x2400.  That's a 1:1 aspect ratio.

Comment: I apologize, I was unclear.  I meant that my starting image is 2400x2400, and I am wondering if I crop it down to fit the TV aspect ratio of 9:16 (yes, it's a vertical screen) then will it fit correctly and not look distorted?

Comment: Yes, you would have to crop it to that specific aspect ratio.  You can use something like Photoshop or GIMP to crop the image to the correct size by aspect ratio. As for how a specific TV would display it is hard to say. It might depend on the software the TV uses to display images, especially if they are in a vertical orientation. Why not just try it and see!  You may find you have to rotate the image 90 degrees, to set the aspect ratio to 16:9. You may also have to select a specific resolution like 720p, full HD, 4K, etc.

Comment: Thak you for the advice!  Unfortunately this is an image being sent to someone on my sales team for a tradeshow across the country, and the only info provided to me was the photo that they wanted used (the 2400x2400 image) and that their tv screen was 40-52".  I don't have the ability to be there to mess around with the TV to make it display correctly which makes this infinitely harder, especially since I normally do packaging material labeling and not show site images haha

Comment: then I would suggest you send them a file to try, and get them to check if it works. I don't think there is any way to predict what the TV will do with the image. There are just too many unknowns.  It may take a bit of back and forth with you and your sales team colleague trying different files. It's a difficult one, but such is life sometimes. Good luck!!

Comment: Thank you for your swift and concise advice!  I appreciate it a ton

Comment: Another thing to try is perhaps to find out the model and make of TV from your colleague.  You could then perhaps look up the user manual online, and find out the specs. It may also have instructions on using the image viewing software installed on the TV.  TV's are so damned complicated these days.  When I was a child, TVs had two dials, a tuner and a volume control, and before anybody laughs,  I'm not even that old. Only 56. LOL!!!!

Comment: I have reached out to the colleague for additional info but their track record of responding is about 50/50 which is why I asked my question here to plan for the worst case scenario of having no other info haha.  I agree TV's have gotten complicated now!

Answer (score 3):

The options you have to present an image with a different aspect ratio than your display are:

- Squish (Please, do not use this)
- Crop
- Resize
- Animate

[image]

---

**Edition 2.**

Normally a TV does not do anything by itself.

1. They need to receive a signal, normally from a HDMI or similar port. So what is shown depends on your computer running PowerPoint for example.
2. Some TVs have some kind of built-in software and a USB plug so they can display the content of the USB, maybe a series of photos, videos, or both. You need to see the TV user manual.
3. Probably some other "software" to read things online. Some can display YouTube content or something similar.
4. They need to receive a broadcast. (But you need to own a TV station... not likely)

The most viable option is number 2.

- Take Gimp which is free.
- Backup your original file
- Your image has 2400px Crop the image X dimension to 1350px. (That number is the 2400px at the base multiplied by .5625 which is the 9/16 proportion.
- Now you can prepare two versions, and resample it to 1920px in height, and automatically will give you a 1080px base, and a second version to 3840x2160px.
- Send them both with the proper name and let the other person choose.

https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMP_Quickies/

---

**Initial answer.**

> I have my image set to 9:16 aspect ratio

If the TV is vertical it is okay. But if not it should be 16:9

> and 2400x2400 resolution,

on what? I suppose that is the original image's size.

> so the image should fit to fill the entire TV screen

That image can not do anything on its own. You need to crop it, resample it, or make a camera movement like vertical panning. Probably the best option is making a video on a video editor doing the necessary actions.

> TV itself has some weird aspect ratio settings

What has a weird aspect ratio is your image. The project settings of a typical TV 16:9 project are either 1920x1080 Full HD or a 4K project, double that 3840x2160.

To maximize quality go for the biggest size, prepare your project as 4k.

---

If you only drop an image, you will be at the mercy of the software handling it. It might crop it, squish it resample it, but with no control of your part.

---

> My assumption is that the TV screen size and resolution shouldn't matter

Yes, it does. Full HD vs. 4k, vertical or horizontal.

<sub>https://www.pexels.com/es-es/foto/mujer-amable-18055559/</sub>

Comment: It is a vertical screen, so 9:16 is the correct aspect ratio.  2400x2400 is the starting resolution of the image that I have to work with.  Can I ask why you would make a video for use as a static image on a TV display?  I don't need the image to move at all, just present and show up correctly on the TV.  I am not sure if the TV is Full HD or 4k, so what would be the best way to proceed?  I have never designed an image meant to fit on a TV screen before so I am a bit lost.

Comment: I added an example of why using a video. Example number 4.

Comment: To maximize quality go for the biggest size, prepare your project as 4k.

Comment: Thank you for the examples!  This is for a work project that's a bit outside my normal job duties so I apologize for any confusion on things I say.  From your examples it looks like I want to do the cropped option with the image that I had provided to me.  I agree with your advice to make the image 4k since I don't know the type of TV I am working with (the screen is 40-52" is the only info about the tv that was supplied to me).  Do you have a suggestion for an easy way I can upscale my image?

Comment: Answer Updated.